# Attach remote gdb to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gdb, gdbserver

I have never used gdb before. I want debug an application running on an embedded linux board.

I have a C++ application running on an embedded linux board. If I have its code loaded up on Xcode 10.1, is there a way to set breakpoints and debug line by line? Some way to attach the remote gdb to Xcode on my machine and debug setting breakpoints the way we can do on other IDEs like *Visual Studio*, *Android Studio* or *QtCreator*?